# Does there exist an equivalent of md-block for direct inclusion of org-mode file in a webpage?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, markdown, web

The *md-block* library can directly render a markdown file in a browser:

[How to Render Markdown on a Web Page With md-block](https://www.makeuseof.com/md-block-render-markdown-web-page/)

I'm already aware of the HTML export functionality in org-mode. This question is about rendering org-mode files directly inside a webpage without access to emacs.